# Determinant Progress Indicator

Tags: swift, swift4, objective-c-swift-bridge, progress-indicator, swift3.2

I’m trying to create a window that displays a determinant progress indicator. This indicator would start loading and once done, fade into the background... revealing the regular macOS storyboard template. I’m not asking for someone to write this code for me but please point me into the right direction. I’d prefer to use swift but will use objective-c if the need arises.

Answer (score 0):

Well one simple way is to simply add a hidden view that you can programmatically make appear whenever you want to display progress.

I recommend using a container view, however, so that you can isolate the progress view's logic to its own UIViewController.  Here's a [recent tutorial](https://naveenr.net/beginning-container-views-in-ios/) on container views.  Doing it this way also allows you to share the progress UI logic with other screens of your app too.

Comment: So, would I be better off making an AppleScript App instead of the Cocoa App. I'm trying to stick with the storyboards for as long as possible. The link does give some useful tips, but it is associated with the iOS platform. I making this for macOS.

Comment: You can totally use a storyboard.  There's a box to check in the UIView's properties inspector to set the view as hidden.  In your UIViewController's code, just tell the view to unhide when you wish the progress indicator to appear.

Comment: The bindings inspector seems pretty simple. I don't know if I would link the progress bar to the NSObject icon or what. Any ideas on this? thanks.

Comment: Should I bind it to the view controller (hidden option)? One last thing is the values in bindings inspector.